# Weird White Line

Tags: html, css

for some reason i'm getting a weird white line on one of my elements.

Heres what it looks like:

[image]

its right next to the Introducing on the left side.

I've looked through the code and cant seem to find it

its located at http://divisionforty.com

I don't know where the problem is so i cant post any code.

Comment: don't look at the code. use a DOM inspector to figure it out. e.g. in firefox, right click the line, then "Inspect Element (q)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the answers were great! However as it turns out i had been blocking part of the code with a comma

This:

```
/* Title Right ----------------------------*/

.title_right, .title_right_services_page h3{
    color: #bd2d67;
    padding: 0;
}
.title_right, .title_right_services_page h1{
    line-height: 45px;
}
.title_right, .title_right_services_page p{
    color: #777;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: 200;
}
.title_right_services_page{
    border-left: 2px solid #cdcdcd;
    position: relative; 
    text-align: right;
    padding:0 0 30px 1%;

}
.title_right,{
    border-left: 2px solid #cdcdcd;
    position: relative; 
    text-align: right;
    padding:0 0 30px 1%;
}
.arrow_right{
    background: url("../img/arrow_right.png") no-repeat center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 53px;
    height: 49px;
    left: -40px;
    top: 40%;
}
.arrow_rightb{
    background: url("../img/arrow_rightb.png") no-repeat center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 53px;
    height: 49px;
    left: -40px;
    top: 40%;
}
```

To this:

```
/* Title Right ----------------------------*/

.title_right h3{
    color: #bd2d67;
    padding: 0;
}
.title_right h1{
    line-height: 45px;
}
.title_right p{
    color: #777;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: 200;
}
.title_right{
    border-left: 2px solid #cdcdcd;
    position: relative; 
    text-align: right;
    padding:0 0 30px 1%;

}
```

And that fixed it!

Thanks All

Denver

Answer (score 0):

The line comes from a `span.arrow_right`.

Answer (score 0):

it's this bit of HTML:

```
<span class="arrow_right"></span>
```